# Batch script to create a new folder with date name and copy xlsx files from the source folder

Tags: batch-file

can anyone help with the following batch script requirement:

I want to create a day wise folder within month folder

Second step is to copy xlsx files from the source folder and paste it in the newly created day wise folder.

[image]

[image]

I am currently using the below script but i have to manually run it everyday

```
@echo OFF
mkdir 5.Oct'21\%date:~-4,4%"-"%date:~-7,2%"-"%date:~-10,2%
move /Y 1.Dump\*.xlsx 5.Oct'21\%date:~-4,4%"-"%date:~-7,2%"-"%date:~-10,2%
```

Comment: Automate it so that it collects the dates each day, then schedule it to run via Task scheduler.

Comment: unfortunately, task scheduler reads this as incomplete. which is why i have not been able to schedule this

Comment: You have not provided us enough technical information.  The `DATE` variable is region and language dependent.  So without knowing what the output of the `DATE` variable is on your computer nobody will know what format you want the date to be in.  Also there is no reason to quote the hyphens.  That is unnecessary.  Best practice is to always surround the entire file or folder path in quotes when using any command that uses file and folder paths.

Comment: I have added the output, hope that is what is required. I would really be helpful if you can provide the entire code even if it is a powershell

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate some `powershell` into your `batch-file` to give you a specific date format. Though I am not a fan of creating directories with quotes, I respect that you want to use it, so here goes:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2*delims=-" %%i in ('PowerShell Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yy"') do md "%~dp0%%i.%%j'%%k" >nul 2>&1
```

That should then create a folder with the given date each time it is launched.

You can then create a scheduled task to launch it on a specific time of day.

Here is an example:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Create_Backup_Folder" /tr "C:\some place\script.cmd" /ST 07:00 /sc DAILY /ru "USERNAME" /np /f
```

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestion, If you have a better solution to this i can surely opt that too... its just that i only knew this way

Comment: also here is the path

Comment: D:\Droom Technology Dropbox\Analytics and Planning\Analytics\13. Trackers\2021\Daily trackers

Comment: I tried incorporating ur suggestion its not really working. I am new to this apologies for that